# best data structure to record a Pareto front

Tags: priority-queue, red-black-tree, pareto-chart, ordered-set

May I ask if someone has already seen or faced the following problem?

I need to handle a list of cost/profit values 
c<sub>1</sub>/p<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>/p<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>/p<sub>3</sub>,... that satisfies:

- c<sub>1</sub>≤c<sub>2</sub>≤c<sub>3</sub>≤c<sub>4</sub>...
- p<sub>1</sub>≤p<sub>2</sub>≤p<sub>3</sub>≤p<sub>4</sub>...

This is an example: `2/3`, `4/5`, `9/15`, `12/19`

If one tries
to **insert** `10/14` in above list, the operation is **rejected** because of the existing
cost/profit pair `9/12`: it is never useful to increase the cost (`9->10`)
and decrease the profit (`14->12`). Such lists can arise for instance in 
(the states of) dynamic programming algorithms for knapsack problems, where
the costs can represent weights.

If one **inserts** `7/20` in above list, this should **trigger the deletion** of `9/15` and `12/19`.

I have written a solution using the `C++` `std::set`  (often implemented with
red-black trees), but I needed to provide a comparison function that eventually
become a bit overly complex. Also, the insertion in such sets takes
logarithmic time and that can easily actually lead to linear time (in terms
of non-amortized complexity) for example when an insertion triggers the deletion of all other 
elements.

I wonder if better solutions exist, given that there are countless solutions
to implement (ordered) sets, e.g., priority queues, heaps, linked lists, hash 
tables, etc.

*This is a Pareto front (obj1: min cost, obj2: max profit)*, but I still could not find the best structure to record it.

Comment: Please, define "best"

Comment: I would like to be able to go through the list by repeatedly applying a constant time `getNext()` function. I understand I need to pay logarithmic time to check if a new pair should be rejected or not (but maybe it can be done more rapidly, who knows?). But I feel it is possible to avoid losing logarithmic time to check if a cost value exists. I would like to do this in constant time as well, for instance by using a second array (or hashtable) along a red-black tree to record the set of costs only.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand the rules you described, so I will agnostically say that an attempt to an insertion might trigger rejection and if it is accepted, then subsequent items need to be removed.

You will need to use a balanced comparison tree, represented as an array. In that case, finding the nodes you need will take O(logN) time, which will be the complexity of a search or a rejected insertion attempt. When you need to remove items, then you remove them and insert a new one, which has a complexity of

O(logN + N + N + logN) (that is, searching, removing, rebalancing and inserting. We could get rid of the last logarithm if while rebalancing we knoe where the new item is to be inserted)

O(logN + N + N + logN) = O(2logN + 2N) = O(logN^2 + 2N), which is largely a linear complexity.